# Passing C# class to javascript (no web server)

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am writing a desktop application in C# and would like to pass data from C# to an HTML 5 panel (javascript or jquery). I am using CefSharp which embeds Chromium into the application, it successfully loads data from a file with no web server, I have this up and running to display Processing sketches locally within the application (desktop).

The solution I am looking for can't use or require a web server, it has to operate locally. The HTML 5 (CefSharp) browser panel is hosted by the application and does not allow users to navigate to web pages. Its only purpose is to visualise and display data the software generates.

Ideally I would like to do something like the following:

Data in C# ----> (possibly) JSON object ----> object available in embedded browser

The browser has an instance of jQuery if that helps. I'd be grateful if you a small code sample can be provided, it has to operate without a web server and preferably without dumping the C# data to a file which is then loaded by the embedded browser. I want to pass data directly from C# to the embedded browser and have it available for processing.

Any ideas?

References:
https://github.com/chillitom/CefSharp

Comment: You can serialize the data using the `JavascriptSerializer` and then set it in a hidden field. Then in the document ready event, you can parse it using `JSON.parse(hiddenFieldData)` and then display to the end user.

Comment: Please refer : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx for a sample.

Comment: can you provide a code example of this technique?

Comment: The example is in the above comment. Please go through and let me know if you have any further clarifications

Comment: Thanks saravanan, does the implementation you have specified work without a web server? I need to pass data from a c# class to the embedded browser without a web service running?

Comment: You can use the serializer to send the data to the page in the browser during page rendering itself. try it and post us your updates.